# Meteor Login User From Server

Tags: meteor, xss, iron-router

I have a cross-site ajax login request coming from a chrome extension to a Meteor app. I am handling this on the Meteor side using Iron-Router and the `where:'server'` setting. The request comes in fine, but now that I have the request, I want to login the user. How do I do that from the server?

I tried getting around it in a hacky way by redirecting from the server to another router using `Router.go('otherRoute', {email:requestEmail, password:requestPassword})` in the `action` callback but that didn't work because the go method wasn't found. Either way, that seems like a poor solution to this problem.

Comment: I'm afraid you cannot do that. You'll need to connect via `webSockets` + `Meteor DDP` to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Roughly speaking, what you will need is more or less a `DDP client` present on your custom (non Meteor?) website. The features you require are implemented in meteor's `livedata` package. There's also a node package [node-ddp-clinet](https://github.com/oortcloud/node-ddp-client) (server side), which you could probably use as a starting point in implementing your own client.

Once you have a working `DDP client`, logging in is a matter of calling `login` method on the server (through `DDP` of course). Look
[here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js) for more details.